# Transloadit not working on cordova/phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, transloadit

I am trying to get transloadit upload working on phonegap app, without success,
XHR and JQuery uploads work on desktop browsers but when trying on phonegap they fail (with JQuery upload the app crash if the transloadit initialization is there) while with XHR it fail with status : 0

If anybody has implemented this before can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working answer for integrating Transloadit with PhoneGap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290133/6236619)

If you're still unable to make it work, please share more details - the code you are using, versions of jQuery and the Transloadit SDK, error messages, and stack trace.

Comment: If you think that answers for this question as well then mark this question as duplicate of that question. Don't post the links to that answer here.

Comment: @NSNoob Aplogies, but A. I don't have enough reputation to flag and B. I'm not sure it qualifies as a duplicate, as it might be a totally different issue and require more details to solve (Unfortunately, I also can't comment)